# Routes/Controller issues with "unfavorite action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I have implemented an add to favorites feature with a has_many :through association. A user is now able to favorite or unfavorite a room in the room show.html.erb view. On a different controller and view I want to display all the favorite rooms of the logged in user.

And I want that the user is able to delete every favorite room. Showcasing all the rooms is no problem unfortunately I can't make this work with the unfavorite button.

**How can I make this work?**

[image]

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :favorite]
...
  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @room
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'You favorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
  def wishlist
  end
```

**wishlist.html.erb**

```
<div>
<% current_user.favorites.each do |room| %>
    <%= room.listing_name %>
    <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  root 'static_pages#welcome'
  get 'wishlist' => 'static_pages#wishlist'

  resources :rooms, only: [:index, :show] do 
    resources :reservations, only: [:create]
    resources :reviews, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  resources :rooms do
    put :favorite, on: :member
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In whishlist.html.erb you are using '@room' instead of 'room'. @room is only set in the rooms controller, not the static pages controller.

Comment: Thanks allot! Could not see this!